# Does the viewcontroller must declare <UIAlertViewDelegate> before respond to alertview

Tags: ios

I saw a code of view controller which implements the following

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 }
```

But I think it need to declare to use the `<UIAlertViewDelegate>`.

However, I cannot find this declaration in the view controller's header file.

I would like to know why the code can respond to the event?

Comment: Do you use UIAlertView? Do you need to perform action depending on which button is touched (ie other than a simple information with an "Ok" button) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocoa often detects the presence or absence of implemented delegate methods dynamically, rather than relying on static types. Therefore it is not necessary to formally declare that your view controller conforms to the protocol `UIAlertViewDelegate`, unless you wish the compiler to warn you of not implementing required methods of the protocol.

Internally, `UIAlertView` checks if the `UIAlertViewDelegate` responds to selectors it is about to call before trying to invoke it, essentially eliminating the need to declare the protocol implementation. This may look unusual to developers coming from statically typed languages, but this is commonplace in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `delegate` property of the `UIAlertView`, at the least. It is recommended, to have the class declare it is implementing `UIAlertViewDelegate`, but is not mandatory. Reason being,
ObjectiveC is dynamic language, the runtime will find the method implementation even if the class is not marked with the protocol.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

No you don't need to implement UIAlertViewDelegate because it confirms to NSObject.